# SExprParser.parseSecretKey : java.io.IOException: unknown character encountered: K

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, gnupg

I'm trying to load secret keys from D:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\private-keys-v1.d using bouncy castle **bcprov-jdk15on-1.66.jar**.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.bouncycastle.gpg.SExprParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PBEProtectionRemoverFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPDigestCalculatorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBEProtectionRemoverFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class LoadKey {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PGPException {
        String filePath = "D:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\gnupg\\private-keys-v1.d\\4B8379C14DED7818D546E3C4AF7F1D0DF5716BCD.key";
        String pass = "siv_test";
            PGPDigestCalculatorProvider calculatorProvider = new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()
                    .build();
            PBEProtectionRemoverFactory passphraseProvider = new JcePBEProtectionRemoverFactory(
                pass.toCharArray());
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);


        PGPSecretKey key =

        new SExprParser(calculatorProvider).parseSecretKey(
                new BufferedInputStream(in), passphraseProvider,
                new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());

        System.out.println("Found key "
                + Hex.toHexString(key.getPublicKey().getFingerprint()));
            
        
    }
}
```

But I'm getting

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: unknown character encountered: K
at org.bouncycastle.gpg.SXprUtils.skipOpenParenthesis(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.gpg.SExprParser.parseSecretKey(Unknown Source)**

gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.23

libgcrypt 1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the SExprParse is accepting only "raw" pgp keys and not "PEM"-ones.

The key in my example is taken from the Bouncy Castle SExprTest.java so it is a **sample key** with the password "**fred**".

As the key is in binary form I'm using a `ByteArrayInputStream` to process the key, this is the link to the complete test: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/test/SExprTest.java.

The program is running successfully and presents a secret key in the end:

```
Found key 228f5c0cd3e1d2716760770be5ac9684b1a77195
```

Maybe one of our Bouncy Castle experts can explain the behavior a little better...

Here is the code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.gpg.SExprParser;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PBEProtectionRemoverFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPDigestCalculatorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBEProtectionRemoverFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.Security;

public class LoadKeySo4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PGPException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        //String filePath = "D:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\gnupg\\private-keys-v1.d\\4B8379C14DED7818D546E3C4AF7F1D0DF5716BCD.key";
        //String pass = "siv_test";
        byte[] key1 = Base64.decode(
                "KDIxOnByb3RlY3RlZC1wcml2YXRlLWtleSgzOnJzYSgxOm4yNTc6AOpclatE"
                        + "WCIXSUA2y44L/jPGE1lU3d75nMN5+iJK/vXFGmQdvZWhewX2LSJ5vwpcLcQ1"
                        + "u3QXRbOcY0o+jRAER2vHZMEfyHfHir6QDibVTO5IOjLettW054hew/HoFbA2"
                        + "v3t0BB2HERWMFO6WLrC7wBVpgL85m85VhE/OmZGIOY7bapQtULoTQQ5Fwr0n"
                        + "+zG3gujxDcmpcTouz0DPtVLvMERnHMtJ4GEccWfiFrGUnLbBnYCnnsNoV/0m"
                        + "f/GseRltCnxPS2Fl+rhdkPmxC0Dkv6naV+NMiaZVk5FYdtY66xATvETv+xTa"
                        + "X8xHIhJc4CrR/e4T0VPBh/94o5nHL1cT6HcpKDE6ZTM6AQABKSg5OnByb3Rl"
                        + "Y3RlZDI1Om9wZW5wZ3AtczJrMy1zaGExLWFlcy1jYmMoKDQ6c2hhMTg6vqXu"
                        + "vvqQtUw4OjI3OTYxMzQ0KTE2OlYbNG/073BvJLzSjbvoxQYpNzM2OkcNABDe"
                        + "gU7iUAJwVxNszEG+ackC6qk7Y+dQ6NN4Avy9pkGo+Rufs0G4yjHhVQMkH0QF"
                        + "Wrzf5GOvsvrJQyJGVLn2amz5KxU+onNv66UVi4D3LlCOghDcGoe/V7hY+zsh"
                        + "GN7elPhnBYbk7X1Jb5D03YrCOOCTnGLTLMc7E5qy4YSyRWMzAGGj/jkcY/B+"
                        + "ZEeLkTlHsnnukIMb24+1/sZrsV57AaVPRZwgzInxDGC9Tkg4j6fsHvvVw6ZD"
                        + "cm+ET/YGOf1dhMKEq/7GXcd5qeEpMBFi+6p2PrPJUwUHu/PIOs1SCIYlrhGR"
                        + "iifAHtOIdFGefo+E1v6kKZMO+FgLTeiGYN6T6vjkG7FMiWwnmamF6qNd1D5i"
                        + "TS2E4uiS5Z3QuwyXJfGkYYDjEmV5rVSol95Kd4wpebC7mFNbOk+zA4TB5Ytb"
                        + "5KN/w2lSW4btuB/pD/akfg6xJQ9BREv1vpO4CtK+d8VLCPHI7et1tKjwJNxd"
                        + "obw9P4HOBIPYdzbHARpAfZRLQlLRNcYp8DbHfzmDhIEPymO6+3CCtdfRE7xY"
                        + "c0SMpFFYGX17WGlmjdOYWtbqYrhDQ3ylzD3vrIQr12ZZXw00xSJkNk4aJ8Lx"
                        + "SihOXTuLiHhueckfCCbkWPfdJQg1ukjRiNgHdEF+7rk/2aMDsSYULJqtjSed"
                        + "CDi9tLqawmCz405E+W+Htbrp2yv7ktST2IaV56JQB4Yay8WAlnngoBtdlSyA"
                        + "wFVFm5VrCeZ5ckdUfK1qSezd32uQlb27XCZYGiaco5AWkhBOrdPoiw4Z14Pf"
                        + "z6xhhV+vA+X6lm9k70iG7RO9vf3V+EAbKktFos72rGJGhWOZgv5xr8DRjbIf"
                        + "/dOQsgceYg4xrTzn/SjOSNmTQu++Q1Uo5jjtMozgXawJNFPKcZ28DLTxdHQl"
                        + "a7jZK/FiiXXBL8J/VbN9DWZq7IOUMEhRym8KcAoyC7wQgpua2qhp8EXX7Qqd"
                        + "7dU4EcdWzzz/lF8pKDEyOnByb3RlY3RlZC1hdDE1OjIwMTgwNTI4VDAyMjIw"
                        + "MikpKQ==");
        String pass = "fred";

        PGPDigestCalculatorProvider calculatorProvider = new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()
                .build();
        PBEProtectionRemoverFactory passphraseProvider = new JcePBEProtectionRemoverFactory(
                pass.toCharArray());
        //InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(key1);
        PGPSecretKey key =
                new SExprParser(calculatorProvider).parseSecretKey(
                        new BufferedInputStream(in), passphraseProvider,
                        new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
        System.out.println("Found key "
                + Hex.toHexString(key.getPublicKey().getFingerprint()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Michael Fehr, Thank you very much for your reply. But our Idea is to load the private key for the given user. My code is working fine with GNUPG version 2.1.X where as it throwing the exception for GNUPG version 2.2.X.

Comment: https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2017-December/033295.html

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question and append a **sample** key with GNUPG version 2.2.X together with the passphrase?